# error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why this code generates a TypeScript error.
(It's not the original code and is a bit derived, so please ignore the non-sense in the example):

```js
interface Images {
  [key:string]: string;
}

function getMainImageUrl(images: Images): string {
  return images.main;
}
```

I'm getting this error (using TypeScript 1.7.5):

> error TS2339: Property 'main' does not exist on type 'Images'.

Of course I could get rid of the error by writing:

```
return images["main"];
```

I'd prefer to not use string to access the property. What can I do?

Comment: Typing `images["main"]` does not throw an error ?

Comment: No, `images["main"] is ok.

Comment: @basarat what are these definitions good for when TS compiler doesn't use it the way one would expect?

Comment: <ng-container class="varience" *ngIf ="vari; else second" > <h1>{{display_vari_price}}</h1> <ng-template #second> <ng-container> <h4 id="rate"> Price : {{ slide.price }}</h4> <h3> Offer Price :{{slide.saleprice}}</h3></ng-container> </ng-template> </ng-container> property second does not exist on this component

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you want to be able to access `images.main` then you must define it explicitly:

```
interface Images {
    main: string;
    [key:string]: string;
}

function getMainImageUrl(images: Images): string {
    return images.main;
}
```

You can not access indexed properties using the dot notation because typescript has no way of knowing whether or not the object has that property.
However, when you specifically define a property then the compiler knows that it's there (or not), whether it's optional or not and what's the type.

---

#### Edit

You can have a helper class for map instances, something like:

```
class Map<T> {
    private items: { [key: string]: T };

    public constructor() {
        this.items = Object.create(null);
    }

    public set(key: string, value: T): void {
        this.items[key] = value;
    }

    public get(key: string): T {
        return this.items[key];
    }

    public remove(key: string): T {
        let value = this.get(key);
        delete this.items[key];
        return value;
    }
}

function getMainImageUrl(images: Map<string>): string {
    return images.get("main");
}
```

I have something like that implemented, and I find it very useful.

Comment: First of all: it's a helpful answer and might be a solution for my problem. But then: what is the sense of declaring "map-like" objects with `[key: string]: aType`?

Comment: A map in this sense is like an array, you access elements with brackets

Comment: I added another way of dealing with maps, check my revised answer

Answer (score 74):

The correct fix is to add the property in the type definition as explained in @Nitzan Tomer's answer. If that's not an option though:

#### (Hacky) Workaround 1

You can assign the object to a constant of type **any**, then call the 'non-existing' property.

```js
const newObj: any = oldObj;
return newObj.someProperty;
```

You can also cast it as `any`:

```
return (oldObj as any).someProperty;
```

This fails to provide any type safety though, which is the point of TypeScript.

---

#### Workaround 2

Another thing you may consider, if you're unable to modify the original type, is **extending the type** like so:

```
interface NewType extends OldType {
  someProperty: string;
}
```

Now you can cast your variable as this `NewType` instead of `any`. Still not ideal but less permissive than `any`, giving you more type safety.

```
return (oldObj as NewType).someProperty;
```

Comment: <ng-container class="varience" *ngIf ="vari; else second" > <h1>{{display_vari_price}}</h1> <ng-template #second> <ng-container> <h4 id="rate"> Price : {{ slide.price }}</h4> <h3> Offer Price :{{slide.saleprice}}</h3></ng-container> </ng-template> </ng-container> property second does not exist on this component

Answer (score 8):

As has already been mentioned,

> Typescript has no way of knowing whether or not the object has that property

so the error is legitimate. But if we check that the property exists before accessing it, Typescript will take that into account and allow dot access:

```
if ("property" in obj) {
  console.log(`Can access ${obj.property}`)
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert in Typescript, but I think the main problem is the way of accessing data. Seeing how you described your `Images` interface, you can define any key as a String.

When accessing a property, the "dot" syntax (`images.main`) supposes, I think, that it already exists. I had such problems without Typescript, in "vanilla" Javascript, where I tried to access data as:

`return json.property[0].index`

where index was a variable. But it interpreted `index`, resulting in a:

`cannot find property "index" of json.property[0]`

And I had to find a workaround using your syntax:

`return json.property[0][index]`

It may be your only option there. But, once again, I'm no Typescript expert, if anyone knows a better solution / explaination about what happens, feel free to correct me.

Comment: This is a completely different problem.

Comment: You are asking what can you do / why do you have the error. I'm trying to explain you why do you have this error, and what could be your options considering my personnal knowledge. As told, anyone could have a better answer, I'm trying to help. The non-definition of a `main` property in your `Images` interface is definitely your problem there.

Comment: No, it's not the problem. The property "main" exists. It's not a runtime-problem, but compile-time. And I'm not accessing the property through a variable, but "main" is really the name of the property.

Comment: Glad that it helped at least one person here :).

Comment: I was getting the error TS2339 on req.header.mod_api_key = 'somevalue' but req.header['mod_api_key'] = 'somevalue' did not give me the error. const a='mod_api_key'; req.header[a] also worked.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with TypeScript 2.2 using dot notation to access indexed properties is allowed. You won't get error TS2339 on your example.

See *Dotted property for types with string index signatures* in [TypeScript 2.2 release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html).

Answer (score 2):

The correct fix is to add the property in the type definition as explained by @Nitzan Tomer.
But also you can just define property as `any`, if you want to write code almost as in JavaScript:

```
arr.filter((item:any) => {
    return item.isSelected == true;
}
```

Comment: <ng-container class="varience" *ngIf ="vari; else second" > <h1>{{display_vari_price}}</h1> <ng-template #second> <ng-container> <h4 id="rate"> Price : {{ slide.price }}</h4> <h3> Offer Price :{{slide.saleprice}}</h3></ng-container> </ng-template> </ng-container> property second does not exist on this component

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on Vue 3. It was because `defineComponent` must be imported like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
        msg: String,
    },
    created() {
        this.testF();
    },
    methods: {
        testF() {
            console.log("testF");
        },
    },
});
</script>
```