# Mongoose "property x does not exist on type y" error - still works

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

With Mongoose, I get `error TS2339: Property 'highTemp' does not exist on type 'Location'` when trying to use dot notation (`model.attribute`) although the code still works as intended. In the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y) I learned that using `model['attribute']`  yields no error.

**What is the proper way to be able to use dot notation with Mongoose without errors?**

Background:

*location.model.ts*

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose');

export const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  lowTemp: Number,
  highTemp: Number,
});

export const Location = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

*data.util.ts*

```
import { Location } from '../models/location.model';

function temperatureModel(location: Location): number {
  const highTemp = location.highTemp;
  const lowTemp = location['lowTemp'];

  // Do the math...

  return something;
}
```

Building the above yields the TS2339 error on `highTemp` but not on `lowTemp`. My preferred method of using model attributes would be with dot notation as in `location.highTemp`. What should I do? Explicitly defining interfaces for every model sounds like pointless work..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `model` method accepts an interface (which needs to extends `Document`) which can be used to statically type the result:

```
export interface Location extends mongoose.Document {
    name: string,
    lowTemp: number,
    highTemp: number,
}

export const Location = mongoose.model<Location>('Location', LocationSchema);

// Usage
function temperatureModel(location: Location): number {
    const highTemp = location.highTemp; // Works
    const lowTemp = location.lowTemp; // Works
}
```