# How can I access props in a component wrapped with custom HOC?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I created a simple HOC, which uses custom hook to track mouse position. I use the hook in the HOC function, and with it I want to pass that value to the wrapped component.

And that's OK, I pass the function as prop, and I can console.log that prop just with `this.props`. I get the output `{position: {…}}` in the console, as expected. When I expand that log object, I can see the output `position: {x: 479, y: 396}`, which is exactly what I want.

But, when I want to access the actual object with `this.props.position`, it just throws me an error:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/dvidovic/Projects/hooks-in-classes/src/components/HooksHOC.tsx(6,28):
Property 'position' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2339
```

Here's the HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useMousePosition } from '../hooks/useMousePosition';

export const withHooksHOC = (Component: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    return <Component position={useMousePosition()} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

And here's the wrapped component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withHooksHOC } from './withHooksHOC';

class HooksHOC extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props); // this works
    console.log(this.props.position); // this throws an error
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '100px', fontSize: '72px' }}>Some text</div>
    );
  }
}

export default withHooksHOC(HooksHOC);
```

What do I have to change to access the position object?

Comment: Does using `this.props['position']` work ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe because you're calling the function when you pass it as a prop? I'm assuming it returns the mouse position object.  Maybe try ```position={useMousePosition()}``` and then ```console.log(this.props.position());```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a generic with an interface of your props to `React.Component`:

```
interface HooksHOCProps {
    position: {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }
}

class HooksHOC extends React.Component<HooksHOCProps> {
...
```