# How do I get a document field from a specific document in Firestore using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying to use Firebase Cloud Functions in my  Flutter application. In my application, I want to retrieve a document field from a certain document when an event happens using typescript. I have done the same thing before in dart however I am unsure of what to do when using typescript. In the code below I attempt to get the field from the document using a method in dart however it fails in typescript with the following error:

```
Property 'snapshot' does not exist on type 'DocumentReference<DocumentData>'. Did you mean 'onSnapshot'?
```

I have simplified the code to one cloud function with the most important parts having comments before them. I am trying to get the nickname field from the personFrom documentReference.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();

export const sendToDevice = functions.firestore
    .document('messages/{groupChatId}/{chatId}/{message}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot: { data: () => any; }) => {


        const message = snapshot.data();
        if (message != null) { 
            const querySnapshot = await db
                .collection('messages')
                .doc(message.idTo)
                .collection('tokens')
                .get();


// **** This is where I am referencing the document where I want to get its fields ****

var personFrom = db.collection('messages').doc(message.idFrom).snapshot();

        const tokens = querySnapshot.docs.map((snap: { id: any; }) => snap.id);

        const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
            notification: {
// **** Right here in the title parameter is where I am attempting to retrieve a specific field of data from the document I mentioned above ****
                title: "New Message from" + personFrom["nickname"]+ "!",
                body: message.content,
                icon: 'your-icon-url',
                click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
            }
        };

        return fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);

        } else {
            return undefined
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you use [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#get) on a DocumentReference to fetch a document. It returns a promise that resolves with a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) object:

```
const personFrom = await db.collection('messages').doc(message.idFrom).get();
const data = personFrom.data();
```

Now, data has a JavaScript object that describes the contents of the document.

Comment: Now that I have the data of the document how do I get a field from that document? Also the code you gave does not compile in typescript. The second line has to be modified to: var data = (await personFrom).data;

Comment: You access fields using properties of the object in the usual JavaScript fashion.  You might want to use the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Can you show me how? I have looked at the documentation you sent and when I tried it out I received several errors with my code. Please remember I am using typescript and not javascript. The code follows: 

const personFrom = await db.collection('messages').doc(message.idFrom).get();
const data = (await personFrom).data; 

var name = data.name;

Comment: So what's the error? and what will `console.log(data)` output?

Comment: @DougStevenson If I try and access the "name" field of the data document with this line of code: var name = data.name;  I get this error: Property 'name' does not exist on type '() => DocumentData | undefined'.ts(2339). When I console.log(data) I get: [object Object]

Comment: This has to do with how typescript handles objects and properties, I am not much into it so check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y) for additional insights.