# Property 'hide' does not exist on type on build

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am new to quasar framework.

I have created one component & used it modal popup. I have followed [this](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#Invoking-custom-component)

Dialog is opening using below.

```
methods: {
  openStoreModal(store:Store) {
    this.$q.dialog({
      component: StoreComponent,
      parent: this,
      title: store.name,
      store: store,
    });
  }
}
```

Html of custom dialog component.

Html

```
<template>
  <q-dialog
    ref="dialog"
    @hide="onDialogHide"
  >
    <q-card 
      class="q-dialog-plugin"
      style="width: 700px; max-width: 80vw;"
    >
```

and inside custom dialog component

```
methods: {
  show() {
    this.$refs.dialog.show();
  },
  hide() {
    this.$refs.dialog.hide();
  },
  onDialogHide() {
    this.$emit('hide');
  },
  onCloseClick() {
    this.hide();
  }
}
```

I am getting this error on build.

[image]

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code but the error is `TS2339` which is generated from the Typescript compiler. I don't think the problem is with quasar-framework.

Please check your interfaces / types as mentioned in this thread: [error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y)

Comment: Issue with `this.$refs.dialog.show()` only. I have given ref to `q-dialog`.  I have added html in which ref is given. Modal dialog open & closes fine when running the app. But it's creating issue on build generation.

Comment: Yup, when you run a build the compiler looks at your code and in this case it's failing to find a definition for hide and show on an element type. If you have a link to your project I could pull and run locally?