# how to convert json map to array ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the json like follow example, i would like to convert this json map to array for to be able to loop on it.

I use the Object.keys method but I don't know how to have a key => value format for the whole json.
I need to get the keys to make a table I know there is the pipe keyvalue but it's not what I need. or maybe I use it wrong

**example json**

```
{
  "pays": "UK"
  "test": [
   [
    "123456", // here i want key id
    "blabla", // here i want key name 
    "lorem ipsum" // here i want key type
   ],
   [
    "654321",
    "ipsum",
    "blabla"
   ]
  ]
}
```

**components.ts**

```
get() {
 this.myService.getUrl().subscribe(data => {
  this.myArray = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
   return {
    id: key,
    name: data[key]
   }
  }):
 }
```

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as a "JSON map". There's JSON, which is a single uninterrupted string that conforms to the syntax outlined on https://www.json.org, and there is plain, normal data in whatever programming language you're working in after _parsing_ the JSON. Before you parse, JSON is JSON, there is no "JSON [datatype name here]", and you can't work on it short of things you can do to strings like charCodeAt or substring or the like. _After_ you parse it, it's normal data, and you can work with it, and code questions about it have nothing to do with JSON but with the data it yielded.

Comment: Also on a TS note: are you sure you're using typescript? Your code doesn't have any type information anywhere, and looks like plain javascript.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i use typescript Angular this is just example. I am also a beginner

Comment: Remember the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): show _your_ code (after reducing it), because that's what's causing you problems. Or of course, write example code but then make doubly sure that it actually has the problem you're trying solve. Having said that, did you already look at [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
var input: any = {
      "pays": "UK",
      "test": [
       [
        "123456", // here i want key id
        "blabla", // here i want key name 
        "lorem ipsum" // here i want key type
       ],
       [
        "654321",
        "ipsum",
        "blabla"
       ]
      ]
    }

    input .test = input.test.map((item: any) => {

      return {
        id: item[0],
        name : item[1],
        type : item[2]
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution to transform array of strings into array of JSONs:

```js
let input = {
  pays: "UK",
  test: [
   [
    "123456", 
    "blabla", 
    "lorem ipsum"
   ],
   [
    "654321",
    "ipsum",
    "blabla"
   ]
  ]
};

let result = {};
result.pays = input.pays;
result.test = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input.test.length; i++){
  let testEl = input.test[i];
  let resultObj = {};
  resultObj.id = testEl[0];
  resultObj.name = testEl[1];
  resultObj.type = testEl[2];
  result.test.push(resultObj);
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer me but at the result.test line I have this error: Property 'test' does not exist on type {} why?

Comment: Could be a problem related to typescript. In typescript you have to explicitly define the object type. Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017155/13897065) answer.