# error TS2339: Property 'coord' does not exist on type 'Mixed'

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get the `lat` & `lon` properties from city object, but I get a Typescript error

Tha JSON schema is like this
`{"_id":"vflv511vfsvsv51","name:"dallas","weather":{"coord":{          "lon":"-96.7836","lat": "32.7668"}}}`
so normally to access them we should write something like this `city.weather.lon`

**Error**

```
[09:52:31] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

src/cities/cities.service.ts:130:30 - error TS2339: Property 'city' does not exist on type 'Mixed'.

130     const lat = city.weather.coord.lat;
                                 ~~~~~

src/cities/cities.service.ts:131:30 - error TS2339: Property 'city' does not exist on type 'Mixed'.

131     const lon = city.weather.coord.lon;
                                 ~~~~~

[09:52:32] Found 2 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

**cities.service.ts**

```
async GetCityWeather(cityName) {
    const city = await this.cityModel.findOne({ name: cityName });

    if (!city) {
      this.getCityLastWeather(cityName);
    }

    const lat = city.weather.coord.lat;
    const lon = city.weather.coord.lon;

    const last7DaysWeather = this.getCityLastXDaysWeather(lat, lon);
...
  }
```

**city.model.ts**

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const CitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
  },
  weather: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed,
});

export interface City {
  id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  name: string;
  weather: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed;
}
```

Comment: Your `city` object may be `null` if there was not any city from your query.

Comment: Yes I noticed that and I replaced getCityWeather() with createCity(). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a typescript problem instead of mongoose (Although I find it strange that `weather` is not defined as `any` in ts ), you can try this:

```
city.weather['coord']['lon']
```

Reference:
[error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y)

Answer (score 0):

city name may likely return null if not found. To guard against that, i suggest you make the city all lower and also trim spaces to make the search more accurate.

```
 const city = await this.cityModel.findOne({ name: cityName.toLowerCase().trim() });
//save city  name in db also as name.toLowerCase().trim()

 if (!city) {
   this.getCityLastWeather(cityName);
 }

 const lat = city.weather.coord.lat;
 const lon = city.weather.coord.lon;

 const last7DaysWeather = this.getCityLastXDaysWeather(lat, lon);
...
}
```