# Why does the react 18.2 tutorial throws TS2339 Property 'X' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Tags: reactjs

I am currently following the [react tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props) but at one point I am getting the **TS2339 Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'** error

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }
}

class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Why do I get this error, but the tutorial is working fine? I know how to fix it by e.g. adding the properties to the class or by using an interface.

```
class Square extends React.Component<{value: string}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
        <button className="square">
            {this.props.value}
        </button>
        );
    }
}


class Square extends React.Component<ISquare> {
    render() {
        return (
        <button className="square">
            {this.props.value}
        </button>
        );
    }
}

interface ISquare {
  value: string;
}
```

But why do I need to change something on my side? As far as I see the tutorial is using the same React version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get this error, but the tutorial is working fine?

Because that is a JavaScript tutorial, not a TypeScript tutorial, and there is no type validation in JavaScript.

Trying to do `React.Component<{value: string}, {}>` in a JavaScript file would be a syntax error.

> But why do I need to change something on my side? As far as I see the tutorial is using the same React version.

Because you're using TypeScript and not JavaScript.